# MySQL fulltext search not returning the exact match starting string

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use mysql fulltext search but it returning all other data but one data is getting missed. Here is the data I in the record.

Main record : `10 6588 SOUTHOAKS CRESCEN`
Search string : `10 6588`

I am running query like this

`select id,listingID,listingArea,subArea,city,listingAddress,status from listings where MATCH(listingAddress) AGAINST ('10 6588' IN BOOLEAN MODE) and status != 'Terminated' and status != 'Expired' limit 100`

Status of the record is `sold`

this query returns data like this

```
710 6588 NELSON AVENUE
1901 6588 NELSON AVENUE
6588 VIVIAN STREET
```

but not 10 6588

Any idea what could go wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Can you build an example using http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? Or at least post the table and indices definitions.

Comment: maybe status is Terminated or  Expired ?

Comment: nope status is sold @AliFidanli

Comment: maybe space between 10 and 6588 is not a space char. can you check that ? @kamran07

Comment: I have built a sqlfiddle, but I'm unable to reproduce the problem. You can check it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a656f2/2/0 . Try to repair the table running the following statements: `ANALYZE TABLE listings;
OPTIMIZE TABLE listings;
REPAIR TABLE listings;` . If this doesn't work try to drop and recreate the fulltext index.

Comment: my mysql db server ```Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
User: padmin@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)```

Comment: ```nginx/1.18.0
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.3
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.4.3```

Comment: not working for me @Daniels118

Comment: Try to search for "10*". if it finds your row, then your space in the data is probably not a space. Also be aware that "10" on it's own is not indexed by default, as it is shorter than the default min word length 3 (innodb)/4 (MyISAM). Your row should be found anyway because of the 6588. But please make sure it actually *is* a 6588, and not e.g. 10 6589, and you just assume that it should behave as 10 6588.